# Recurrent neural network for object tracking & position filtering?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, image-processing, recurrent-events, recurrent-neural-network

Would a recurrent neural network be appropriate for object tracking tasks? Mainly I will have 3D feature vectors $(x, y, t)$ where $x$ and $y$ are the positions of an object in the image and $t$ is either the current timecode or a number indexing the current frame being processed.

Since $x$, $y$ always have noise and are just "approximately" located in an image the network would have to do some de-noising. Finally the object should be tracked and the next feature vector $(x, y, t_{t+1}$) estimated.

I guess a Kalman filter would perform quite well for this problem but since the image sequences will have highly different noises (based on lighting and the object to be tracked) I assume an architecture which can learn those additional features would perform better?!

My first idea was using an Elman network to keep it simple...however I would highly appreciate any input on this topic because I do not want to "waste time" on solutions just to notice that they barely work later on.

I also read about recurrent neural networks mimic a Kalman Filter's behaviour but I have no experience whatsoever in which scenarios this would be helpful or producing good results.

**Any experience, advice, literature or somehow related post** is welcome :)

Comment: Nobody has any interesting ideas / sources?

Comment: I am not sure if you still need advice, but check out: http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~mobile/Papers/2016AAAI_ondruska.pdf

Comment: Yeah, I'm always open minded for feedback or ideas. Thank you!